# In a BIND.. Weird DNS issue

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nslookup, dig

I have now somehow replicated a weird issue with one of my DNS zones on two different servers and with two different versions of ISC BIND.

I have a sub-domain delegated to my server. The first time this issue reared its ugly head was for an A record that pointed to 192.168.1.254. For LAN-based queries the server always responded appropriately with 192.168.1.254. However for WAN-based queries it would magically know the public IP address of the DNS Server and respond with that.

The second go around with a new box and the newest version of BIND the problem manifested itself not with 192.168.1.254 but now with 192.168.1.253.

I have done enough testing though know that it is not a caching issue. I have also experimented by changing the record around; i.e. different lines in the file, different names, different IP addresses. The only way this issue goes away is if I change the record's IP address to something other than .253.

The only thing I can come up with is that BIND chokes on that record and instead returns the IP address associated with the NS record???

Anyone else see anything like this? Have a theory on what's going on?

Comment: So, you had an A-record that maps Host1.sub.example.com to 192.168.1.254, and when a device on the LAN asked your BIND server for the A-record for host1.sub.example.com, it got back 192.168.1.254 like you expected. But when a device outside of your LAN queried the DNS system (not necessarily your BIND server directly?) for the A-record for host1.sub.example.com, whatever DNS resolving server it sent the query to, responded with the public IP address of your BIND server? Do you have packet traces of the working and failing cases?

Comment: Post your named.conf file (and 'includes') and the zone filename(s) and contents, then we'll also need resolver configurations on the system(s) you're using to query DNS and *exact* command line params used.  There are too many moving parts to even make a guess without those details.